# Is it possible to use SAS to connect to Microsoft Azure in Python?

Tags: python, azure

Currently i am working on a project which submits data to the Microsoft Azure platform.
I'm using a service bus which contains various queues and subscriptions.
Since i am developing for the Raspberry Pi i decided to use the Azure SDK for Python found on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python).

To make sure not every device can delete messages i want to have some policies. Microsoft Azure supports [Shared Access Signature Authentication (SAS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn170477.aspx) and [Access Control Service (ACS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/hh403962.aspx).
Yet i haven't found a way to use SAS with the Python library.

I am fairly new to using Python so it could be that i am just looking over it, but some help or directions would be appreciated.